# how to get Json response from my node.js server and display it on web(ejs) page

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

i want to know how i can get a json response from my node.js server and display the response on my web page

below is the request and reponse in json code

```
var request = require("request"),
    username = req.body.username,
    password = req.body.password,
    url = "https://api.ecoachsolutions.com/main.php?ecoachsignin=1&server=remote&user="+username+"&pass="+password;


    console.log("url is "+url);
    request.get(
    {
        url : url
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        // Do more stuff with 'body' here
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var json_body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json_body); 
        var msg = json_body.profile.user;//this is the message i want to show on my web page(msg)
    console.log(msg); // get json response
  }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to register express to use ejs:

`app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);`

then you can use `res.render` and pass your data to the view

```
res.render('index.html', {msg: json_body.profile.user});
```

After that you can access that via the EJS

```
<%= msg %>
```

If you need a working example, a good one can be found at:

https://github.com/strongloop/express/tree/master/examples/ejs